# How can I mute/unmute all sounds of some files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, audio, game-development, mute

I'am creating a game that have some storage sounds host in JavaScripts files, like this:

```
let gameOver = false;
let gameWin = false;

const gameOverSound = new Audio("sounds/fim.wav");
const gameOverSound = new Audio("sounds/fim.wav");
const gameWinSound = new Audio("sounds/gameWin.wav");
```

Can I create a button in my **index.html** to when click, he switch to mute/unmute the sound of this files... **Is that possible? How?**

**My project contain 5 files in JavaScript, i want to mute all of then**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. The click function will stop the music when it happens

```js
let gameOver = false;
let gameWin = false;

const gameOverSound = new Audio("sounds/fim.wav");
const gameOverSound = new Audio("sounds/fim.wav");
const gameWinSound = new Audio("sounds/gameWin.wav");


let stopButton = document.querySelector("DivClass or DivID");

stopButton.onclik = ()=>{
gameOverSound.pause()
gameWinSound.pause()
}
```

Comment: I have 5 files of JavaScript.js, I'am using the **canvas tag** to reder all the files in the index.html. I would put this code in all the JavaScript files or in the <script> tag in my index.html?

Comment: You should put this code in the part where the Audio methods are, but you should import this javascript code into the html file where the button is.

Comment: Not working for me... I set up the button like this:  `<button type="submit" class="neon" id="volume">
        <strong> <i class="fa fa-volume-up" id="audio"></i> &nbsp; Som</strong>
      </button>` then i did as you said early in my Game.js: `let gameOver = false;
let gameWin = false;
var gameOverSound = new Audio("sounds/fim.wav"); 
var gameWinSound = new Audio("sounds/gameWin.wav");

let stopButton = document.querySelector("#muted");

stopButton.onclik = ()=>{
gameOverSound.pause()
gameWinSound.pause()
}`... but nothing is happining 

Comment: Your button class name is neon, but you have assigned the onclick event to a div with a muted id. You should set the stopButton variable as follows.

let stopButton = document.querySelector(".neon")